# Product of definite integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f,g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions. Show there exist $\alpha\in (0,1)$ for which

$$
\int_\limits0^1f(x)dx\int\limits_0^1g(x) dx=g(\alpha)\int\limits_0^\alpha f(x)dx + f(\alpha)\int\limits_0^\alpha g(x) dx .
$$

I don't understand this problem at all.  Can somebody give me a kickstart?

Comment: Hint: Mean value theorem

Comment: Set $F(t) = \int_0^t f(x) \, dx$ and $G(t) = \int_0^t g(x) \, dx$. You are then to show that there exists $\alpha \in (0, 1)$ such that $(FG)(1) - (FG)(0) = (FG)'(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 2):

By hypothesis $f(x), g(x)$ are both continuous functions on $[0,1]$ hence the integral function  $$F(t)=\int_{0}^{t}f(x)dx\cdot\int_{0}^{t}g(x)dx$$ is a continuous and derivable function in $[0,1]$.

$F(t)$ satisfies the hypothesis of Mean value theorem, so $\exists\alpha\in(0,1)$ such that $$\frac{F(1)-F(0)}{1-0}=F'(\alpha)\iff F(1)=F'(\alpha)$$ where $$\begin{matrix}F(1)&=&\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx\cdot\int_{0}^{1}g(x)dx\\ F(0)&=&\displaystyle\int_{0}^{0}f(x)dx\cdot\int_{0}^{0}g(x)dx=0\end{matrix}$$ and $$F'(\alpha)=f(\alpha)\int_{0}^{\alpha}g(x)dx+\int_{0}^{\alpha}f(x)dx\cdot g(\alpha)$$ It follows from the formula used to find the derivative of product of two functions.